# Do I really need to add the com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync() method to all of my Activities?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm currently trying to make the mobile ads with facebook work for my android app.
I did all of the steps required, except the one where I need to add the method:

```
com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync();
```

to all of my activities in the `onResume()` method.
My questions is - do I really have to put this method in ALL of my activities, and if yes - why?
I'm concerned that if I do so - my app will run slower.
Maybe if I put it in the first Launching activity only, it will still work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method, as the name implies, runs on a different thread, so unless your app is very resource constrained, should not affect the performance.  It will also handle tracking repeat calls to prevent multiple installs being reported, so once it reports on first install, it won't report again.

Comment: Ok, thank you but still - what if I do a single call - only on my launch activity?

Comment: I think that's fine, but if any connection failures occur, your app will need to take care of retrying the call (which is essentially what this code does), otherwise you won't get proper attribution.